# Battary draining fast

Tags: power-management, battery, acer

I'm using Acer Aspire E 15 E5-576G.

I installed Ubuntu last year. After installation, I noticed that my battery drains faster than usual.

Because of that, I had to remove Ubuntu and use Windows instead.

I had no similar problem in Windows. The battery works very well, it works 5-6 hours. So, I think the problem does not belong to the hardware.

Last week, I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows and I have the same problem as before.

How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me the same on 20.04. I think it's something with Nvidia X Server Settings. If you're lucky, you can switch to power saving mode. Look at this picture:

[image]

Comment: This was helpful .
Here a full explaining of this method 

https://askubuntu.com/a/1244247/1087563

Answer (score 2):

Your Ubuntu distribution consumes more power than Windows for graphics. Remember, Windows has big money behind it and the graphics (and others) drivers are optimized for performance. One other issue that causes faster battery drainage is the rate of keeping graphical display active.

If battery power is so important, try something from an older post:

[Ubuntu consumes too much battery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841057/ubuntu-consumes-too-much-battery)

Hope I've helped.