# Battery drainage and overheating while using Ubuntu on Acer Laptop

Tags: nvidia, power-management, battery, acer, overheating

I have the very same issue as given in this link- [Battary draining fast](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243991/battary-draining-fast/1353419#).

I'm using Acer Nitro 7 which has NVIDIA GeForceGTX 1650 with 4 GB of dedicated GDDR5 Graphics card(mentioning this bcoz I think the most probable issue is bcoz of the graphic card).

I installed Ubuntu 18 last year. After installation, I noticed that my battery drains faster than usual and also overheats henceforth fans rotate fast and make noise.

Because of that, I had to remove Ubuntu and use Windows instead.

I had no similar problem in Windows. The battery works very well, it works 5-6 hours. So, I think the problem does not belong to the hardware.

Last week, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows as dual boot and I have the same problem as before. Ubuntu hardly gives me a backup of 1.5 hours.
I have already installed tlp, powertop, and required Nvidia driver which [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/841057/ubuntu-consumes-too-much-battery) suggests but still the battery backup has not increased.

Did I miss something in these solutions? Plz, help me how can I solve this problem as I'm stuck over this for 2 days.

Comment: Does the battery drain as fast when you use the power saving mode as in this answer? https://askubuntu.com/a/1243994/124466

Comment: yeah, I didn't observe any significant change after turning on the power-saving mode :(

Comment: Check that `options nvidia "NVreg_DynamicPowerManagement=0x02"` is set somewhere in `/etc/modprobe.d/*` (this should have happened automatically when you installed the driver). E.g. run `grep NVreg_DynamicPowerManagement /etc/modprobe.d/*`. For maximal power savings you could also run your laptop using just the IGD. Not being a gamer or graphics designer (I do use the card for compute work) I never quite understood why I'd want e.g. Firefox to do its graphics processing on the NVidia card. A waste of power for what, 10µs faster page rendering? I rather have 9+ hours on battery.

Comment: I can't find --options Nvidia "NVreg_DynamicPowerManagement=0x02 which u were suggesting in any files inside /etc/modprobe.d/. Can u provide a more detailed answer?! Also, what's the IGD thing?! Sorry, if these feels a bit silly questions, but I'm very new to Linux(Ubuntu) environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Nvidia on demand driver(U can configure this from Nvidia X server settings application)

[image]

has improved my battery backup twice(3 hrs now), though lesser than what I used to get while using windows i.e, 5hrs.

On the other hand, I didn't observe any significant change after turning on the power-saving mode(i.e battery backup of 1.5 hrs only).

PS- I'm using Powertop too.

---

****Update**: I have found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1134726/1372248)
as the most appropriate one, that actually improved my battery life from 3 hrs to 4.5 hrs(on a full charge).
So In case, it solves your problem too, plz upvote his answer.**

*`Though I'm satisfied with this amount of battery life, still Update If u can further help in enhancing/improving the battery life.`*